# Filter JComboBox items

Tags: java, swing, filter, jcombobox

I have some object

```
public class SomeObject
{
    private boolean isActive;

    private String name;

    public SomeObject(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isActive()
    {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(boolean isActive)
    {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }
}
```

and a `JComboBox list;` I am adding roughly 90 or so `SomeObject`s to the `list` using `list.addItem(someObject);`

I also have a button `JButton toggle;` and upon pressing that button I would like to filter JComboBox to display items that have true for `isActive();`

In `JTable` I use `TableRowSorter` with `RowFilter` in order to achieve that. What are the equivalent for `JComboBox`?

Comment: `Every solution I look at gives example of type as you go` so clicking a button is just like typing a character. You create a new model containing only the active items and then reset the model of the combo box.

Comment: @camickr they do not filter, just bring up searched value most of the time.

Comment: They create a new model by only adding items that satisfy the search criteria. There is no equivalent to the RowFilter of a JTable.